# To upload metadata for s3 image upload using python

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, png, content-type

I am uploading image using python boto3 to s3. Not able to set metadata field for s3 object to "image/png".
code:

```
s3.put_object(Bucket=settings.AWS_STORAGE_PRIVATE_BUCKET_NAME,
                      Key=s3_storage_path,
                      Body=file_content,
                      Metadata={"Content-Type":"image/png"},
                      )
```

Metadata gets set by system to "binary/octet-stream"

Answer (score 0):

When using [`put_object`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.put_object), the content type is set via the `ContentType` parameter, not via `Metadata`.

> ContentType (string) -- A standard MIME type describing the format of the contents. For more information, see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17 .

Try:

```py
s3.put_object(
    Bucket=settings.AWS_STORAGE_PRIVATE_BUCKET_NAME,
    Key=s3_storage_path,
    Body=file_content,
    ContentType='image/png'
)
```